# How to remove brackets from SQLAlchemy filter parameters?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am trying to filter a SQLAlchemy model inside of an Ubuntu Docker Container using OBDC drivers provided by MS, but when doing a filter_by the driver is adding square brackets to the parameters

I tried running this exact code on a Windows box, and the parameter is formatted as `sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('4')` instead of `sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (['4'])`

```py
def get():
    reqargs = request.args
    data = tblData.query.filter_by(**reqargs).all()
    data = DataSchema.dump(data).data
    return {'status': 'success', 'data': data}, 200
```

URL: https://{internalhost}/getData?ID=4

SQLALCHEMY_ECHO log:

```
2019-04-11 17:00:00,148 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT [tblData].[CreatedDtTm] AS [tblData_CreatedDtTm], [tblData].[CreatedBy] AS [tblData_CreatedBy], [tblData].[UpdatedDtTm] AS [tblData_UpdatedDtTm], [tblData].[UpdatedBy] AS [tblData_UpdatedBy], [tblData].[ID] AS [tblData_ID],[tblData].[Description] AS [tblData_Description], [tblData].[AdditionalNotes] AS [tblData_AdditionalNotes], [tblData].[IsEnabled] AS [tblData_IsEnabled] ,
FROM [tblData] ,
WHERE [tblData].[ID] = ?
2019-04-11 17:00:00,148 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (['4'])
```

Error:

```
(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type 4. (2715) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. I need to add `.to_dict()` to the args

```py
    def get(self):
        reqargs = request.args.to_dict()
```